# Strange mapping behaviour from String to Boolean

Tags: c#, .net, azure, automapper

By mistake, someone from my project wrote in the automapper profile the following sentence:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Appointment, AppointmentModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.DeclineStart, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.DeclineStart.ToString()))
```

Where `DeclineStart` is the property of the entity and the model classes.

```
public class Appointment
{
   public bool DeclineStart { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentModel
{
   public bool DeclineStart { get; set; }
}
```

I know that in this case it is not necessary to create any mapping rules for this property.

To my surprise this mapping (from `String` to `Boolean`) is working.

But when we have published our application on Azure cloud service, this code become to throw the `AutoMapperMappingException` which shows that:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:String -> Boolean (System.String -> System.Boolean)
Destination path: AppointmentModel.DeclineStartBackfill.DeclineStartBackfill
Source value:False
```

How it's possible that the same code is working locally, but isn't working on Azure?

Thanks in advance!

---

Azure machine configuration: Windows Server 2012 R2 / .NET Framework 4.5.1

Local machine configuration: Windows 7 / .NET Framework 4.5.2

Automapper version: 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of your AutoMapper assemblies getting deployed, including the AutoMapper.Net4.dll assembly? That additional assembly has extensions available in .NET 4 that aren't available elsewhere, including type converters.

You have two options: manually reference something inside of the .NET4.dll assembly:

```
public static class LinkerHelper {
    public static object BecauseAzureDeploymentsAreDumb() {
        var foo = typeof(HashSetMapper);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Or upgrade to the latest beta version of AutoMapper, where I've combined the platform-specific assemblies.

Comment: Hmmm, no. But why it happened - I'm not able to understand.

Comment: All my dependencies are loaded by Nuget (for automapper it's: <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />). And locally on my dev machine this assembly (AutoMapper.Net4.dll) is loaded, but on Azure virtual machine - not. Actually there is only one AutoMapper.dll exist.

Comment: So if you update to the pre-release, this goes away. It's because there isn't code that references the types in the .Net4.dll assembly, and even though you referenced it, the deployer thinks "hmmm nothing using this so I won't deploy". It's stupid and I fixed this in the 4.0 prelease by just making 1 assembly.

Comment: Please, edit your answer according to the previous comment and I will accept it.